# How to bring K3s server & pods up again after k3s-killall.sh

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I am having K3s cluster with system pods (`kube-system` namespace) & my application pods (`xyz-system` namespace) running.

I want to stop all of the K3s pods & reset the containerd state, so I used [/usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/upgrades/killall/) script and all pods got stopped (at least I was not able to see anything in `watch kubectl get all -A`. K3s and kubectl are still installed, as I can see k3s -v output.

Can someone tell me how to start the k3s server up again because now after firing `kubectl get all -A` I am getting message `The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

**PS:** - When I ran `k3s server` command, for fraction of seconds I can see the same above pods(with same pod ids) that I mentioned while the command is running. After few seconds, command get exited and again same message `The connection to the...` start displaying. Does this means that `k3s-killall.sh` have not deleted my pods as it is showing the same pods with same ids ( like `pod/some-app-xxx` )?

Comment: Which version of k3s did you use and how did you deploy it? On which node did you execute the `kubectl` command?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested 1.21 - The killall script cleans up containers, K3s directories, and networking components while also removing the iptables chain with all the associated rules. The cluster data is not be deleted.

POD-IDS will remain the same. You can also check [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819099/how-to-start-k3s-server-after-running-k3s-killall-sh-script) for how to restart k3s after killall script:

Summariing:

1. run `sudo systemctl restart k3s`
2. run k3s -v, and check for restarts count
3. review pod status